# Como crear relaciones entre tablas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hay distintas maneras para crear una relación en las tablas, lo que consiste hacer uso de las Foreign Key (FK),

Tengo estas maneras entendidas de hacerlo:

**1) En el caso de la creación de FK por codigo SQL**...  para crear una FK seria:

```
FOREINGN KEY(codigocliente)REFERENCES cliente(codigocliente),
```

que diria: La CLAVE FORANEA es "codigocliente" haciendo REFERENCIA a la tabla "cliente" que posee el campo codigocliente
Eso si.. habría que crear el campo codigocliente también en la tabla que lo hereda con las mismas características que en su tabla original. Ya que si no se crea antes ese campo, no se puede usar el `USING` a la hora de un `JOIN` cierto? habría que usar para consultar varias tablas el `ON` o el `WHERE` cierto?

**2) Si creo las relaciones por Workbench a que me autogenere código**, Workbench devuelve algo así:

```
CONSTRAINT `cedula_c`
FOREIGN KEY ()
REFERENCES `tallermecanico_hd`.`c_clientes` ()
```

Esta manera en que trabaja Workbench no la entiendo, porque pone Constraint? y porque no coloca nada entre los paréntesis del FK?

**3) En phpMyAdmin crear el campo como un INDEX para luego abrir la ventana de modo gráfico y crear las relaciones desde ahí**, todo muy lindo sin embargo no se que código genera apartir de ahí.. seguro algo raro parecido al de Workbench tengo que hacer la prueba..

**4)**(*este no estoy muy seguro si estoy en lo correcto, esta es mi DUDA PRINCIPAL*)**En phpMyAdmin** No crear el campo que sera el FK en la tabla que hereda e irse al apartado de **Vista de relaciones y aparece la sección que dice Restricciones de clave foranea**,
Donde se coloca el nombre de la restricción de la FK, (¿**esto aquí hará que se cree el campo que no habíamos creado antes**?) luego colocamos si es `ON DELETE` Y `UPDATE CASCADE` o los otros.. y en el siguiente apartado me enredo porque no se que poner realmente.. o es que igual si tenia que crear antes el campo heredado en la tabla para luego ponerlo en el primer campo que me piden???  por ultimo se seleciona la BD, la tabla y el campo con el que se relacionara...

**Como pueden ver mi duda esta en la ultima manera que coloque**... puse las otras para aprovechar si pueden apreciar que este algo incorrecto.. gracias por haber tenido la paciencia de leer mi pregunta.

Comment: Debe haber un problema con tu instalación de WorkBench puesto que este no debería construirte esa sentencia incompleta.

Comment: Mmm vale considerare ese comentario gracias... que me sugieres vuelva a instalar workbench para asegurar? o tal vez simplemente no habré llenado bien el workbench en el modo grafico?

Answer (score 1):

Sea la siguiente linea un patrón para la creación de una nueva tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla` (/* fragmento */)
```

A continuación definiré solo los fragmentos referentes a la creación de un campo característico para así enfocar la atención en este aspecto en especifico.

**Definición de llave primaria**

```
`campoPrimario` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`campoPrimario`)
```

**Definición de una llave primaria compuesta**

```
`campoPrimario1` INT NOT NULL,
`campoPrimario2` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`campoPrimario1`, `campoPrimario2`)
```

**Definición de un indice único**

```
`campoUnico` INT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX `unico` (`campoUnico` ASC)
```

**Definición de un indice único compuesto**

```
`campoUnico1` INT NOT NULL,
`campoUnico2` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX `unico` (`campoUnico1` ASC, `campoUnico2` ASC)
```

**Definición de un indice**

```
`campoIndice` INT NOT NULL,
INDEX `indice` (`campoUnico1` ASC)
```

**Definición de un indice compuesto**

```
`campoIndice1` INT NOT NULL,
`campoIndice2` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
INDEX `indice` (`campoIndice1` ASC, `campoIndice2` ASC)
```

**Definición de campo foráneo**

```
`campoEnForanea` INT NOT NULL,
INDEX `indiceForaneo` (`campoEnForanea` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `foraneo`
  FOREIGN KEY (`campoEnForanea`)
  REFERENCES `tablaForanea` (`campoEnForanea`)
```

**Definición de llave foránea**

```
`campoEnForanea` INT NOT NULL,
INDEX `indiceForaneo` (`campoEnForanea` ASC),
PRIMARY KEY (`campoEnForanea`),
CONSTRAINT `foraneo`
  FOREIGN KEY (`campoEnForanea`)
  REFERENCES `tablaForanea` (`campoEnForanea`)
```

Tenga en cuenta que los nombre de los indices usados anteriormente como *`«indice, unico, foraneo, indiceForaneo»`* deben ser únicos en las bases de datos. Para evitar duplicar por accidente estos nombres de indices usted puede optar un patrón cualquiera por ejemplo:

```
indice         `index_tabla_campo`

unico          `tabla_campo_unico`

indiceForaneo  `fk_tablaDestino_tablaOrigen_idx`

foraneo        `fk_tablaDestino_tablaOrigen`
```

Claro que esto ultimo es solo una recomendación desde mi punto de vista personal.